# Topology - Intersection of a Comeager Set and an Open Set

Tags: general-topology

Assume $X$ has a topology $\tau _X$ of open subsets of $X$ (call an open set $U$), and there is a comeager subset of X called $C$.

Is $C\cap U$ a comeager subset of $U$ and if so, is there a reference to a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true.

$C$ is comeager, which implies $X\setminus C = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i$, where $\text{int} (\overline{D_i}) = \emptyset$ for all $i$. Then $(X\setminus C) \cap U = U\setminus C = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i \cap U$. The closure of $D_i \cap U$ in $U$ is a subset of the closure of $D_i \cap U$ in $X$, which has empty interior in $X$. And since every open set in $U$ is an open set in $X$, $\text{int} (\overline{D_i \cap U}) = \emptyset$ for all $i$.

Hence, $U \setminus C$ is meager in $U$, so $C$ is comeager in $U$.